# Multivariate distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent random variables with normal distribution $n(0, \sigma^2)$. Let $Y = (X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2)^{1/2}$. Find the density of $Y$.

I tried finding the densities of $X_1^2, X_2^2, X_3^2$ first. For example, $f_{X_1^2}(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z} \sigma} e^{-\frac{z}{2 \sigma^2}}$. The densities of $X_2^2, X_3^2$ are analogous.

Because $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent, $X_1^2, X_2^2, X_3^2$ are also independent. Let $ Y= X_1^2 + X_2^2$. Then the density of Y is the derivative with respect to y of

$$
\begin{align}
F_Y (y) &= \int_0^y \int_0^{y-z_2} f_{Z_1}(z_1) \, f_{Z_2}(z_2) \, \mathrm{d}z_1 \, \mathrm{d}z_2 \\
&= \int_0^y \int_0^{y-z_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z_1} \sigma} e^{-\frac{z_1}{2 \sigma^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z_2} \sigma} e^{-\frac{z_2}{2 \sigma^2}} \, \mathrm{d}z_1 \, \mathrm{d}z_2 \\
\end{align}
$$

I'm not sure how to differentiate this integral though. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2$ is distributed as $\chi^2$ with 3 d.f. divided by $\sigma^2.  $ Its square root is the Maxwell distribution:

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Maxwell_distribution

To derive it, switch to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Your $Y^2$ is distributed as [$\chi^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

Your computation does go in [the right direction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution).